# Attach a photo to an email from my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, email-attachments, file-sharing

I have an iPhone application that picks a photos from the photo album built in App. Now I want to add a sharing button with an option of sharing this photo by email , I can attach an existing photo through this code :

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@""];


// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""]; 
[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];


// Attach an image to the email
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"project existing photo" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"photo name"];

// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

But what do I need to change in this code to attach the picked photo album into the email body ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "attach the picked photo album into the email body"?

Comment: I have a button where the user can pick a photo from the photo App I need to make the user be able to attach that picture in an email body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UIImagePickerController` to allow the user to pick an image. It will then call this delegate method.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    // Your e-mail code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it works you saved my day. Do you have any idea if this gonna work with sms messages? I have searched the web but i did not find any help.

Comment: There is no way to send an MMS within the app. All that you can do is copy the image and launch the messages app where the photo can be pasted.

Comment: So how the apple photo App does that? They don't let developers do what they can do.

Comment: Can you please provide with a sample code for copying and pasting a photo to MMS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hi Use UIImagePicker For Select Image From PhotoLibrary of Camera And Use MFMailComposeViewController For send the email.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

// Dismiss PickerViewController 

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 

// Get Image Fro Attachment

UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

// Setup Email Settings Like Subject, Message , Attachment


MFMailComposeViewController *mailPicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailPicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[mailPicker setSubject:@"Image Attachment Test"];


// Set recipients

NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"xyz.gmail.com"]; 
[mailPicker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

// Set body message here
NSString *emailBody = @":)";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

// Attach Image as Data 
[mailPicker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"photo name"];

[self presentModalViewController:mailPicker animated:YES];

[mailPicker release];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a **UIImage** from the image picker (or any other source), you first need to create an **NSData** object from the image. Use either the **UIImageJPEGRepresentation** or the **UIImageJPEGRepresentation** functions. Once you have the **NSData** object, add it as an attachment like you did in the code you posted.

In most cases, the image will appear in the email after the main message body.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Do you have any idea if this gonna work with sms messages? I have searched the web but i did not find any help.

Comment: That's a separate question. Post a new question on SO.