# how to attach camera roll images to mail composer

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am having a problem where I'm attaching text and a image to the mail composer my textfields attach fine however when i try to attach an image selected from my camera roll i get a question mark? is it because i have not taken a picture from a ios device, and i am just downloading images from google to test it. Also the application works as follows: 
user takes picture and sees it in the UIImageView and then can type his contact details and name and send, or can choose a picture from their camera roll.

.h

```
@interface xyzViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate> {
IBOutlet UILabel *label;
IBOutlet UITextField *field;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *TakePhoto;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *SelectPhoto;

- (IBAction)savedata:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)loaddata:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)dismiss1:(id)sender;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *mytextview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *mytextview1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

@end
```

.m file

```
@interface xyzViewController ()

@end

@implementation xyzViewController


- (IBAction)savedata:(id)sender; {
NSString *savestring = _mytextview.text;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savedstring"];
[defaults synchronize];

NSString *savestring1 = _mytextview1.text;
NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults1 setObject:savestring1 forKey:@"savedstring1"];
[defaults synchronize];

}

- (IBAction)loaddata:(id)sender; {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring"];
[_mytextview setText:loadstring];
[label setText:loadstring];

NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadstring1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring1"];
[_mytextview1 setText:loadstring1];

}

- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender {
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}
- (IBAction)dismiss1:(id)sender {
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}


 - (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)sendButton:(id)sender {
MFMailComposeViewController *mailContoller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
[mailContoller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
NSString *email = @"avip606@gmail.com";
NSString *email1 = @"avi_sp@hotmail.co.uk";
NSArray *emailArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:email, email1, nil];
NSString *message = [@[_mytextview.text, _mytextview1.text] componentsJoinedByString: @"\n"];
[mailContoller setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image);
[mailContoller addAttachmentData:data
                        mimeType:@"image/png"
                        fileName:@"image.png"];
[mailContoller setToRecipients:emailArray];
[mailContoller setSubject:@"IT WORKS!"];
[self presentViewController:mailContoller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[[self mytextview] resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


@end
```

Comment: images or image? you meant single image taken by camera?

Comment: check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVujK57x-74), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966944/attach-a-photo-to-an-email-from-my-iphone-application), [this](https://www.google.com.kw/search?q=attach+image+to+email+iphone&rlz=1C5CHFA_enKW503KW503&oq=attach+image+to+email+iphone&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.8927j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=attach+image+to+email+iphone+xcode)

Comment: i ment image, sorry for the confusion and yes it will be taken by the camera.

Comment: check my second link... that will solve your problem...

Comment: im sorry but i still cant figure this out

Comment: I cannot have full code, but I will try to exlpain what you will do in answer... I believe you know how to attach image in email...

Comment: the link you sent me is for attaching my own image, i want to take a picture and attach to email or select the image from camera roll

Comment: see my answer... I am creating image in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

Comment: where would i insert the last piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to take photo use

```
- (IBAction)takePhotoCam:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

To choose from gallery use

```
- (IBAction)choosePhotoFromLibrary:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now use delegate to read that photo and attach in email...

```
#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
    filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myCameraImage.png"];

    NSLog(@"saving data at === %@", filePath);
    [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Now in Documents folder, you have image called `myCameraImage.png`

Now let's say you have button called Send on email. On clicking create IBAction and attach myCameraImage.png to email.

See [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-create-email-attachment/), how to attach image to email.

Comment: where would i insert the photo and attach in email code though?

Comment: that will be IBAction for the button. see link how to attach image http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-create-email-attachment/

Comment: @avi : is problem solved?

Comment: well no because the picture they take doesn't get attached to the email for some reason.

Comment: @avi : try to find the problem or ask another question and mark this question accepted